# Mobile Broadband connection disconnects everytime

Tags: wired-networking, mobile-broadband, ubuntu-15.04

I have `LG G3 (32GB/3GB)` When I tried USB tethering with my Ubuntu vivid it connected but after about 20-30 seconds it disconnected. I tried with two laptop which are running Ubuntu vivid. And it refers to `Mobile Broadband` and It shows me that `you're now connected to home network` and then I created a new mobile connection but it also doesn't work or I couldn't make it with correct configuration. Do you have any suggestions?

I want to use it as `wired connection` but it always change the type of connection as mobile broadband. And it doesn't connect. I had clicked to connect it, it shows me `you're now disconnected!!`

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a connection account with your service provider's details?
Click on Mobile connection -> add account, then create it correct ASP details.
Then try to connect, if your service provider uses proxy, then you have to update proxy details too.
As i know you can't use it as a wired connection.

Comment: I typed all ASP information like on my phone and still not working!! Therefore, I can use it as wired connection on `previous version of ubuntu` or at least my old phone can refuse the mobil broadband.

Comment: Try to run this command from terminal
sudo pppoeconf 
If its not working, check this thread for more details
http://askubuntu.com/questions/347900/cannot-make-mobile-broadband-connection-in-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: Which commands I need to run ?

Comment: try this command
sudo pppoeconf

Comment: Please use back quote when you are write `code `

Comment: Sorry this also not working